# How to exclude code from production in build-time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

How do I exclude typescript code from webpack bundle during build-time?

For example, I have this line of code in `app.ts` (nodejs application):

```
const thisShouldNotBeInProductionBundleJustInDevBundle = 'aaaaaaa';
```

I want when I build my app using webpack configuration to exclude this code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In webpack version 4 you are able to set `mode: 'production'` in your webpack config. (https://webpack.js.org/concepts/mode/)

So in your source code you can use the following:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const thisShouldNotBeInProductionBundleJustInDevBundle = 'aaaaaaa';
    ...
}
```

In conclusion all code inside if and ifs themself will be automatically removed during building your bundle

Answer (score 4):

Webpack has a `mode` setting, which allows you to switch between development and [production builds](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/).

In your code you can use `process.env.NODE_ENV` to find out wether you are in production or not, Webpack uses that property to eliminate "production dead code":

```
 // declare variable everywhere to prevent unresolvable variable references
 let onlyInDev = "";

 // The following should be shaken away by webpack
 if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
   onlyInDev = "test";
 }
```

If the value is a sensitive information that should not be leaked to your production build, I would search for it in the bundle to make sure that it doesn't get leaked if the building pipeline changes.